# how to hide the folder path from webpack require() in Angular

Tags: angular, webpack

like this one: (its all over the debug console of the webpage)

`__webpack_require__("../../../../../src/app/error/error.component.ts");`

I don't want the users to see the folder structure of the app, 
Is there a way to hide those folder paths?

Comment: The packed application should not have these folder paths.

Comment: how do I remove it ? @Ling Vu

Comment: Try to build it with `ng build` and open `dist/index.html`. This is the packed build output and should not have these console outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: I had to build the Angular project with this command:

```
ng build --prod --aot=true
```

setting the prod to true and AOT to true (Ahead of time compilation) fixed the problem and the files are generated to full js and their name and folder paths are hidden completely